# Как сравнить строки одного массива в Java?

Tags: java, foreach

Допустим  есть массив

```java
String[] names = {"Bill", "Den", "James", "Den", "Loris", "Bill", "Den"};
```

Как можно сравнить в цикле for (или по другому) эти строки друг с другом?
Моя задача именно в том, чтобы вывести имена строк (элементов массива), которые повторяются и  вывести количество раз каждой строки, которая  встречается в массиве.

Вот конкретный пример, но здесь что-то не так точно.

```java
static public Map<String, Integer> getDuplicate(ArrayList<Unit> list) {
    Map<String, Integer> dupEl = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (list.get(j).equals(list.get(i))) {
                dupEl.put(list.get(i).toString(), ++count);
            }
        }
    }
    return dupEl;
}
```

Юнит класс ничего необычного, тестовый класс  :

```java
public class Unit {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Unit(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Unit unit = (Unit) o;

        if (age != unit.age) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(unit.name) : unit.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + age;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name='" + name;
    }
}
```

Раз на то пошло, вот сам список и вызов метода:

```java
ArrayList<Unit> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

mylist.add(new Unit("Edik", 40));
mylist.add(new Unit("Bill", 35));
mylist.add(new Unit("Grace", 25));
mylist.add(new Unit("Jason", 37));
mylist.add(new Unit("Edik", 40));

/* 1) Найти дубликаты  в списке
 * 2) Вывести название дублируемого объекта
 * 3) Указать количество раз, когда встречается объект в списке.
 * */
getDuplicate(mylist).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Comment: Создайте ассоциативный массив (HashMap), где ключом будет строка, а значением - число. Пустите цикл по массиву. В каждой итерации проверяйте есть ли в HashMap строка из массива. Если да - увеличьте число по ключу. Иначе - добавьте ключ и число 1. В итоге у вас будет HashMap с ключами-строками из массива и значениями - количеством повторений слов в массиве.

Comment: Юрий, правда так и делаю, но где-то делаю что-то совсем не так.... Исправьте, если можете.

Comment: Покажите код - посмотрю

Comment: вот, посмотрите

Comment: Вы переусложнили, кажется, сейчас напишу как надо)

Comment: буду очень благодарен , вижу что велосипед придумываю

Comment: Только покажите что у вас за Unit такой

Comment: вот,  прислал, обычный тестовый класс

Comment: Не хотите дубликатов, используйте: `putIfAbsent`. И собственно `computeIfAbsent`. Профит! И не придется писать костыли и говнокод.

Comment: Дело не  в этом, задача была найти дупликаты и посчитать их количество у каждого элемента

Comment: `Stream -> filters` в помощь.

Comment: А допустим по моей задаче, как именно через Stream-filters решилась бы она?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предложу еще такое решение со стримами

```
public static Map<Unit,Long> getDuplicate(List<Unit> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, мне все варианты интересны

Answer (score 2):

```
static public Map<Unit,Integer> getDuplicate(List<Unit> list) {

    Map<String,Integer> dupEl= new HashMap<>();

    for (Unit unit : list) {
        if (dupEl.get(unit) == null) {
            dupEl.put(unit, 1);
        } else {
            duplEl.put(unit, duplEl.get(unit) + 1)
        }
    }

    return dupEl;
}
```

или если Java версии 8+

```
public Map<Unit,Integer> getDuplicate(List<Unit> list) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach(unit -> map.put(unit , map.getOrDefault(unit , 0) + 1));
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна именно карта `Map<String, Integer>`, то в данном случае поле `age` и методы `equals`, `hashCode` и `toString` вообще не нужны, потому что они не используются.

Чтобы собрать дублирующиеся элементы листа в карту, можно использовать метод [`stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```java
public class Test {
    public static class Unit {
        private final String name;

        public Unit(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    static public Map<String, Integer> getDuplicate(ArrayList<Unit> list) {
        return list.stream()
                // собираем в карту
                // дублирующиеся объекты
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        // ключ - строка,
                        // поле 'name'
                        e -> e.name,
                        // значение - количество
                        e -> 1,
                        // суммируем колличество
                        Integer::sum));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Unit> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new Unit("Edik"));
        myList.add(new Unit("Bill"));
        myList.add(new Unit("Grace"));
        myList.add(new Unit("Jason"));
        myList.add(new Unit("Edik"));

        getDuplicate(myList).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Edik: 2
Grace: 1
Bill: 1
Jason: 1
```